# SSIS Lookup Transformation error: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_describe_undeclared_parameters'

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssis, etl, lookup

I'm upgrading SSIS packages from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2017. After upgrading one of the packages, the parameterized query in the `Advanced` tab of a `Lookup Transformation` is now throwing a validation error. It is possible that this is the only package in the collection that uses a `Partial Cache`, since I couldn't find any successfully upgraded examples to compare it to.

When I tried to run the package, it logged these errors:

> Error: 2019-02-11 10:49:40.11
>      Code: 0xC0202009
>      Source: Anonymized DFT [209]
>      Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_describe_undeclared_parameters', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.".
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2019-02-11 10:49:40.15
>      Code: 0xC020824C
>
> Source: Anonymized DFT [209]
>      Description: OLE DB error occurred while loading column metadata. Check SQLCommand and SqlCommandParam properties.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2019-02-11 10:49:40.18
>      Code: 0xC004706B
>
> Source: Anonymized DFT SSIS.Pipeline
>      Description: "Anonymized DFT" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2019-02-11 10:49:40.22
>      Code: 0xC004700C
>
> Source: Anonymized DFT SSIS.Pipeline
>      Description: One or more component failed validation.
>   End Error
>   Error: 2019-02-11 10:49:40.27
>      Code: 0xC0024107
>
> Source: Anonymized DFT
>      Description: There were errors during task validation.
>   End Error

I was hoping to just re-map the parameters, but I get about the same set of errors by trying to open the `Parameters` dialog on the `Advanced` tab of the `Lookup Transformation`.

The obvious answer, based on the messaging, is that it's a permissions issue, but according to the [documentation for sp_describe_undeclared_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-undeclared-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions):

> Permissions
>
> Requires permission to execute the @tsql argument.

Both I and the service account that the job runs under have permission to execute the parameterized query.

I did a side-by-side comparison of the both the `Lookup Transformations` and their corresponding `Properties` windows between the 2008 R2 package, which runs fine on the 2008 R2 server, and the new 2017 package. The only new property value I found was `TreatDuplicateKeysAsError`, but changing that has no effect on my situation.

Looking at the `Advanced Editor`, the column references in the `ParameterMap` appear to be correct, but the query isn't picking them up.

Is there more to the permissions issue than I'm seeing, or is there something else that I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the `TargetServerVersion` of the package?

Comment: @Hadi, I'm going to take this down. I missed that it was a cross-server lookup, and on the target of the look up query, permissions for the sp are explicitly denied. Getting a DBA to fix that for me now.

Comment: @Hadi, I actually found a different solution, so I undeleted the question in case my suffering might help somebody else. The answer to your question is that he `TargetServerVersion` is `SQL Server 2017`. Which is kind of correct. The server where most of the action happens is 2017, though the one I'm doing some of the Lookups against is a 2012 box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't point to a specific source that suggested this as a possibility, but in the end I added an additional `Connection Manager` pointing to the same server and database as the original, but instead of using the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` provider, I changed it to `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server`.

Boom. Validation error cleared; package is running.

While that's a solution, it's not a explanation, so if anyone wants to chime in, have at it. I've wasted most of a day chasing this ghost, so for the time being I'm going to take my running package and call it good enough for a Tuesday.

Comment: There's a two day waiting period to accept your own answer. When I checked yesterday, the line in the sand was still a few hours away and I forgot to come back for it later. Thanks for the reminder, @Hadi.